# Change print style (landscape , portrait) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

Currently I have create 2 css file , to simplify : the main difference between them are:

print.css

```
@page {
  size: landscape;
}
```

print_single.css

```
@page {
  size: portrait;
}
```

For the html file , it quote one of the css first

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id ="printCSS" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Then if it is printing single page , I use jquery to change the path of the css file, otherwise , it will print in landscape  :

```
    $(doc).ready(function(){
      $('#singlePrint').click(function(){
      $('#printCSS').attr('href','css/print_single.css');
    });    
});
```

The problem is , it seems only work in Chrome, I tried it on firefox and ie, the css file path is changed, but the css file is not reload , how to fix the problem ? thanks.

Comment: Not all of the @page properties are supported by all the browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: Thanks. but I tried on IE8 and FX. latest ver.  It should be support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@page{size: landscape;} will not support in firefox. Alternative way is to use this in css class

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

Comment: .body or .page. both will be fine.

Comment: Rotation is 0. check this link for more details.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Check this link for rotation of text and image..http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotate

Comment: Sorry. I found that it still can not change the orientation in printing preview for FX and IE.. eg. If default is landscape , then no matter what css is used, the orientation is still landscape in print preview, how to fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30809/discussion-between-anna-p-and-user1871516)